# Moving Object in a specified path in a browser through scrolling up/down.

Tags: javascript, css, html, dynamic

Fellas I wanted to create a website in which a object moves down on a particular specified **path** while **scrolling down**. And goes in **reverse** direction when **Scrolled UP.**

For ex. the sea monster here [**www.appmiral.com**](http://www.appmiral.com)

In my case it would be a **car** coming down with a certain path defined when scrolled down. I wanted to know the technique used. can it be done only with **CSS and javascript.**

> For example:this is kind of a model to show what I need in Actual sense.

[image: Yellow car moving on red path through scrolling up/down]

Comment: Honestly no idea, but Google is [almost promising](http://community.createjs.com/discussions/easeljs/490-is-it-possible-to-move-a-display-object-along-a-path)

Comment: Thanks for the response. But its not THE answer to my problem. It has its own complexities of path background and moving car.But thanks again,your link led to somewhere close to what I am trying to do.